# Minimal three.js skeleton animation?

Tags: three.js

I want to understand how three.js animates rigged models in glorious low-level detail. Here's my current code:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);

camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

scene = new THREE.Scene();

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 1, 1);

for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    geometry.skinIndices.push(new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0));
    geometry.skinWeights.push(new THREE.Vector4(1, 1, 0, 0));
}

var bones = [];

var bone1 = new THREE.Bone();
bone1.position.x = 5;
bones.push(bone1);

var bone2 = new THREE.Bone();
bone2.position.x = -5;
bones.push(bone2);
bone1.add(bone2);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x156289 });

var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
var skeleton = new THREE.Skeleton(bones);

mesh.add(bone1);
mesh.bind(skeleton);
scene.add(mesh);

skeletonHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(mesh);
skeletonHelper.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add(skeletonHelper);



function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  var time = Date.now() * 0.001;

  mesh.skeleton.bones[0].rotation.z = Math.sin(time) * 2;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

The `SkeletonHelper` is visibly animated but the box isn't. How do I fix my code to animate the box?

Here's a CodePen pen with the above code:

- [An Anonymous Pen on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmEmrE?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

To fix, just add a `skinning: true` property to the material. So this line:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x156289 });
```

would become something like this:

```
var material =
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x156289,
        skinning: true
    });
```